# Is $(Id-\Delta)\colon H^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$ bijective?

Tags: analysis, differential-operators

Is

$$(Id-\Delta)\colon H^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega),$$

with Neumann or Dirichlet boundary conditions, bijective? I know that this holds, but why? ($\Omega$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n=2,3$ and smooth boundary)

My first Try: $(\lambda-\Delta)$ is bijective for $\lambda<0$ since $\rho(\Delta)\subset \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ but is is it possible that 1 is in $\rho(\Delta)$ too?

My second Try: $-\Delta$ is bijective. Does my claim hold for an easier reason than above?

Sry if there is some bad english and thanks for help.

Comment: With $\Delta$ I mean the Laplace-Operator

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $(I- \Delta) u =0$, then

$$0 = \int_\Omega u(I-\Delta)u dx = \|u\|_2^2 + \|\nabla u\|_2^2.$$

Thus $u =0$. So $I-\Delta$ is injective. Since $I-\Delta$ is Fredholm of index zero, this implies that $I-\Delta$ is also surjective.

Comment: Thank you, but what does "is Fredholm" mean. I didn't hear about a property named Fredholm.

Comment: @MorphhproM : Please see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_operator). I will also try to explain that in a different way.

Comment: Now I found this post:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735024/why-is-delta1-an-isomorphism-between-sobolev-space-w2-p-and-lp
do you know a book were I can read about the proof for p=2 with Fourier Analysis?

Comment: I doubt if fourier analysis can be used here, as $\Omega \neq \mathbb R^n$ in your case. @MorphhproM

Comment: could you add a proof why $I-\Delta$ has Index 0 and maybe you know a good book with the proof why a Fredholm-Operator with Index 0 is surjective?