# Are $\| \Delta u \|_{L^p(\Bbb R^d)} + \| u \|_{L^p(\Bbb R^d)}~~~~and~~\| u \|_{W^{2,p}(\Bbb R^d)}$ equivalents norms?

Tags: banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

> Do we have that  $$\| \Delta u \|_{L^p(\Bbb R^d)} + \| u \|_{L^p(\Bbb R^d)}~~~~and~~\| u \|_{W^{2,p}(\Bbb R^d)}$$ are equivalent norms

This results is pretty easy and straightforward for $p=2$ using techniques via Fourier transform and Plancherel.
But what could we use in place of Fourier transform when $p\neq 2?$

Please prove or disprove or provide me with some good reference where I can fine this .

I fact I need to show that Domain of the generator of the Gauss-Weierstrass semi-group in $L^p(\Bbb R^d)$ is $W^{2,p}(\Bbb R^d)$. this result is counter part for the case $p=2$ where the domain of the generator is $W^{2,2}(\Bbb R^d)$ any help regarding this is welcome

Comment: This should do it, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735024/why-is-delta1-an-isomorphism-between-sobolev-space-w2-p-and-lp?rq=1

Comment: [Riesz transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_transform) is bounded on $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$, hence the affirmative answer in this case. Negative for $p=1,\infty$ via explicit counterexamples  such as $f(x,y) = xy\sqrt{-\log(x^2+y^2)}$ where $\Delta f$ is bounded near $(0,0)$ but $f_{xy}$ blows up there. (Multiply this by a smooth cutoff)